# How to use set up decimal precision for all double type numbers in a large C++ program

Tags: c++, floating-point, double, precision

How to use set up decimal precision for all `double` type numbers in a large C++ program.

I can use `stringstream` and `setprecision(n)` to do it but I have to do it one by one for every `double` number in the whole program.

How to do it globally once for all so that all `double` type numbers in the program has fixed decimal digits after decimal point (e.g. `4`) ?

I do not want to use function call to cause calling overhead.

thanks

Comment: As I answered before, you cannot change the precision of a double: it is what it is. So I'm afraid that I don't understand the question. Do you want to truncate a double value to the fourth decimal position? Or do you want to define a type that behaves like a double but with 4 fixed decimal positions?

Comment: I want the later. So, I used stringstream and setprecision and << operator. I know how to do it. But, I do not understand why your function is more efficient than what I have done ?

Comment: It is not more efficient, see my new answer.

Answer (score 2):

`double` type is not designed to do what you want: it is a floating decimal type, not a fixed decimal type. What you need is some kind of decimal type, but unfortunately C++ does not yet have such type.

It can be emulated most of the times with an integer type where you assume that it represents the then-thousandths of a unit. You just have to be careful in the multiplications and divisions to fix the scale. Additions and subtractions work automatically.

Comment: http://www.trenki.net/content/view/17/1/, http://drdobbs.com/cpp/184401992?pgno=1, or roll your own.  Its not particularly tricky.

Answer (score 0):

`setprecision` does not change the precision of double values, but just the precision used when converted into a string.

And converting doubles into strings is relatively expensive operation, so the overhead of a single extra function call should be negligible. If you use double-string conversion in performance critical code, then you are doing it wrong.

My advice would be to just write a function such as:

```
std::string FmtDbl(double d)
{
    std::ostringstream os;
    os << std::setprecision(4) << d;
    return os.str();
}
```

And use that function everywhere you need the conversion.

Comment: thanks, but your function also need to do double to string converting, and then I need to convert string to double again from the returned value of your function. It also have calling overhead. Why you function is more efficient ? thanks